# Firebird field name escaping

Tags: escaping, firebird

This query works:

```
SELECT r.ID FROM SomeTable r
```

But the next gives me `Token unknown - "ID"` error:

```
SELECT r."ID" FROM SomeTable r
```

Why is this, and what is the way to properly escape field names in Firebird?

Comment: What is the dialect of the database? Dialect 1 does not support quoted object names, and double quotes in dialect 1 are simply (char) strings. My guess would be that the database is dialect 1.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel, yes it was `Dialect1`, I update database server to 2.5 and it is `Dialect3` now. Is there way to migrate to `Dialect3` on the firebird1.5?

Comment: Dialect 3 has been the default since the beginning of Firebird (which means: since Interbase 6). So your database has been explicitly created as dialect 1 (or it pre-dates Firebird), this could mean it requires/depends on specific dialect 1 behavior. For notes on upgrading dialect 1 to dialect 3, see the Interbase 6.0 Getting Started, chapter "Migrating databases to dialect 3". It is available from http://www.firebirdsql.org/en/reference-manuals/ (under Interbase 6.0 Manuals, full set)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using a dialect 1 database (or you have connected with dialect 1 as the connection dialect). Dialect 1 doesn't support quoted identifiers, it has been deprecated since before Firebird existed (when it was still Interbase 6 beta in 1999/2000).

In dialect 1, double quotes are used for strings (char/varchar), so the parser doesn't see `"ID"` as an object name, but as a string, so it throws a *Token unknown* error as it is expecting an object name.

If this is a new database then restart with a dialect 3 database. If this is an existing database, then you really should consider migrating it to dialect 3. See "Migrating databases to dialect 3" in the Interbase 6 Getting started manual (available from http://www.firebirdsql.org/en/reference-manuals/ it is in the Full Set linked at the end of the page).

Answer (score 0):

I check this issue on the firebird2.5 and it doesn't repeat on it.
It discovered only on the old `Firebird1.5` server.
So, correct solution is server upgrading to 2.5 with less amount of bugs :)